# Gradle Docker plugin connection timed out

Tags: gradle, build, docker

I am trying to create and build an image by using [bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin). The Dockerfile is created but I can't seem to be able to build an image from it. I am on Centos 7.

Create the Dockerfile:

```
task createBaseImage(type: Dockerfile) {
    destFile = project.file('docker/base/Dockerfile')
    from 'java:8'
    runCommand 'apt-get update'
    runCommand 'apt-get -qq -y install python3 python3-dev python3-pip'
}
```

Build the image:

```
task buildBaseImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    dependsOn createBaseImage
    inputDir = createBaseImage.destFile.parentFile
    tag = 'the/tag'
}
```

When running the buildBaseImage task `./gradlew buildBaseImage --info`, the execution hangs and finally fails with:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 192.168.59.103:2376 [/192.168.59.103] failed: Connection timed out
```

I suspect there's a problem with my docker closure which is copied from the examples:

```
docker {
    url = 'http://192.168.59.103:2376'

    registryCredentials {
        url = 'https://index.docker.io/v1'
        username = '${docker_user}'
        password = '${docker_password}'
        email = 'email@example.com'
    }
}
```

I've tried different urls, ports etc. but the problem persists. Any ideas about what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around this by using [a different Gradle plugin](https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker). The images can be built in a similar and simple fashion:

```
task buildBaseImage(type: Docker) {
    baseImage 'java:8'
    applicationName = "app-name"
    tagVersion = 'latest'

    runCommand "apt-get update"
    runCommand "apt-get -qq -y install python3 python3-dev python3-pip"
}
```

And then pushed to Docker Hub via:

```
task pushBaseImage(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'buildBaseImage') {
    executable 'docker'
    args = ['push','-f', getGroup() + '/my-base']
}
```

Using force to skip the push confirmation.

> docker push --help
>
> -f, --force=false               Push to public registry without confirmation

This was my way of working around the connection issues.

Here's the required configurations:

```
apply plugin: 'docker'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2'
    }
}

group = "myGroup"

docker {
    maintainer 'Maintainer "maintainer@example.com"'
}
```